# Return travel from UK to non-EU country

Tags: uk, passports, passport-renewals, ukraine

I am a Ukrainian citizen, permanently living in the UK with indefinite leave to remain. The UK is my permanent place of residence and where I work. I have never owned an adult passport but wish to travel to Ukraine to visit family and come back to the UK.

If I obtain a Ukrainian passport, will I be able to come back to the UK without applying for a visa? How does it work? Do I need some sort of document to come back to the UK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I obtain a Ukrainian passport, will I be able to come back to the UK without applying for a visa?

Yes, if you have your residence permit and have been absent from the UK for less than two years.

> How does it work?

Take your UK residence permit with you, and show it to the airline when you check in.  Also show it to the UK passport inspector when you arrive.

> Do I need some sort of document to come back to the UK?

Yes, you need your residence permit.

If you do not have your residence permit, because it was lost, stolen, or damaged, and you have been absent from the UK for less than two years, you can get a [replacement BRP visa](https://www.gov.uk/biometric-residence-permits/lost-stolen-damaged).

If you have been absent from the UK for more than two years, you can apply for a [returning resident visa](https://www.gov.uk/returning-resident-visa).